# Missing validate() method in a command class

Tags: validation, grails

I'm having some hard time figuring out what's wrong in this simple code:

This is a command I made for changing the password:

```
package myapp.commands

import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder as RCH
import myapp.User

class PasswordCommand {
String currentPassword
String password
String passwordConfirm
private u

User getUser() {
    def id = RCH.requestAttributes.session?.user?.id
    if (!u && id) {
        u = User.get(id)
    }
    return u
}

static constraints = {
    currentPassword blank: false, validator: { val, cmd ->
        if (cmd.user && cmd.user.password != val)
            return "user.password.invalid"
    }
...
}
```

And in the appropriate controller I use this action:

```
 def doPassword = { PasswordCommand cmd ->
    if (!cmd.hasErrors()) {
        User user = cmd.getUser()
           ...
```

Unfortunately, I get an Error 500 when I try to change the password:

```
URI: /Myapp/user/doPassword
Class: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
Message: PasswordCommand.validate()Z
```

What is going on ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `@Validateable` annotation:

```
import grails.validation.Validateable
...

@Validateable
class PasswordCommand {
...
}
```

Comment: By naming it *Command shouldn't it be validateable by convention?

Comment: Exactly, I have a second command in the same directory and it works just fine without any annotations! Btw - the annotation *does* fix the problem